# Modal View Controller Won't Start in Landscape Mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, modalviewcontroller

I have a navigation based app that has a detail view (UIWebView) with action buttons across the bottom in a UIToolbar.  I want to add 'notes' when the 'notes' button is pushed.  Everything works fine when the webview is in portrait mode.  I press the notes button, the modal view opens fine and works great.

The problem occurs when the webview is in landscape mode.  If I press the notes button, all the code to open the modal view gets called but all I get is a white screen.  One comment: If I open the modal view in portrait and then rotate the device, it rotates fine into landscape mode.  It just won't *open* correctly in landscape mode.

I have another button that brings up the mail composer which has the identical behavior.  Here is the code in my UIWebViewController:

```
- (IBAction)addNotes:(id)sender 
{
    NotesViewController *notesViewController;

    // create the view controller and set it as the root view of a new navigation
    // controller

    notesViewController = [[NotesViewController alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:self.record.primaryKey];
    UINavigationController *newNavigationController =  
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:notesViewController];

    // present the navigation controller modally

    [self presentModalViewController:newNavigationController animated:YES];
    [notesViewController release]; 
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; // not sure if I need this!  I was trying different things...
    [self.devotionText setNeedsDisplay]; // ditto...
    [newNavigationController release];
}
```

Any ideas?  I've tried all sorts of different things to no avail. I just get a white screen with no navigation bar (although there is a status bar at the top).

Comment: Are you on the latest OS? I've had problems with pushing a landscape-only modal view while in portrait on 3.1.3...

Comment: Yes, I'm running the 4.0 SDK...

Answer (score 7):

Modals don't always get information about rotations, and they get their info from the status bar, which doesn't always work right.  Put this in your viewWillAppear to fix: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation` And, if you want a navigation controller inside your modal, you need to create one.

Also, you don't need the setNeedsDisplay.  That only effects the current views, not the modal you are presenting.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly!  I tried putting the statusBarOrientation code into my NotesViewController viewWillAppear and I still get the same behavior!  I also removed the new navigation controller and still don't get anything...just the white screen.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some code for the initWithPrimaryKey function? Posting some code on that file will help immensely!

Comment: The init function is simple...the xib file is just a UIView with a UITextView under it.

Comment: Actually the nib is just a UIView and I create the UITextView programmatically.  (I've tried it both ways...)

Comment: Have you tried logging your subviews?  Add in a NSLog in viewWillAppear that prints out the subviews (self.view.subviews) to make sure your textfields are actually getting created. Are they?  Have you stepped through this in the debugger?

Comment: Yep.  The textview is getting created.  I have set the background view to blue and the textview to red (to debug).  I even commented out creating of the textview subview.  When I open the notes view (the blue one) in landscape, it still shows a white screen (not blue).  I'm thinking that maybe it has to do with frames/layouts/layers?  I'm completely stumped...

Answer (score 4):

Answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250747/1449618

```
Use the window's root view controller to present:

[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:masterView
                                                  animated:YES
                                                completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I lost days over that issue ... but I found a solution!

I had the same problem you had: the method "presentModalViewController:animated:" only worked in portrait mode.

After a lot of trial and error, I found out that the reason was that I had several view controllers active at the same time. I implemented a navigation system which switched between different view controllers, with one parent handling the children. (I could not use UINavigationController, because I needed a different look.)

So, my root view controller had a root view object, and several child view controllers. When a child view controller was activated, its view object was added as subview to the view of the root view controller.

The "presentModalViewController" method didn't like that. However, as soon as I set the "parentViewController" property of the child view controllers, it worked!

The problem is only that "parentViewController" is a read-only property. You have to extend the UIViewController class so you can access it.

```
@interface UIViewController (HelperExtension)

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *parent;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (HelperExtension)

- (UIViewController *)parent
{
    return self.parentViewController;
}

- (void)setParent:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    [self setValue:parent forKey:@"_parentViewController"];
}

@end
```

So, whenever you add the view of a child view controller to your parent view controller, call the "setParent:" method after doing it. Then it will work!

Comment: This also worked for me. You weren't using BCTabBarController by any change, were you? So much trouble for those little animating arrows...

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue when presenting modally a navigation controller. Be sure to have correctly implement : shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    BOOL shouldAutorotate = NO;
    if( isControllerMangingAllOrientations )
    {
        shouldAutorotate = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        shouldAutorotate = (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
    return shouldAutorotate;
}
```

I was setting the boolean in the viewDidLoad method, not a good idea. Putting it in the initWithNibName:bundle: method is the right place.

Comment: fighting with this exact issue and forgot that by default XCode 4 is adding:

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
  return  (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}`

No wonder it was always portrait.... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

If you use presentModalViewController just for animation like me, you can use pushViewController with animation as below answer;

[Showing pushviewcontroller animation look like presentModalViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838219/showing-pushviewcontroller-animation-look-like-presentmodalviewcontroller)

and you can close the viewController as below;

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I had the task to show a video player in landscape mode.

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
//Player init code goes here....

// #define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0) - was defined previously in a class header

playerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
playerViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a new [Navigation Controlle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)r.

```
- (IBAction)addNotes:(id)sender {

 NotesViewController *notesViewController;

 // create the view controller and set it as the root view of a new navigation
 // controller

 notesViewController = [[NotesViewController alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:self.record.primaryKey];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController: notesViewController animated: YES];
 [notesViewController release];
}
```

Comment: I removed the navigation controller and am still getting the same behavior.  Thanks so much for replying.  Any other ideas?