# Showing pushviewcontroller animation look like presentModalViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Is it possible to show `pushViewController` animation look like `presentModalViewController` but that has background functionality of `pushViewController`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this :

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

[UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: yourViewController animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do this with iOS 8 Style transitions?

Comment: Is this code doing as its says? As its not for Making animation like Present View Controller.

Answer (score 57):

If you want to a fade animation, this approach works.

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gridController animated:NO];
```

Comment: This is the best approach I've found so far. Other methods were causing errors in the frames of the view, or in the navigation controller bar itself. This animation is working awesomely!

Answer (score 25):

For display PushViewConttroler animation as Present below code is working,

For **Push**

```
 ViewController *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
 CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
 transition.duration = 0.4f;
 transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
 transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
 [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                    forKey:kCATransition];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:NO];
```

And for **POP**

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.4f;
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                            forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

There is 1 issue though, that its display light black background when its going up/down,
Working on that, As soon as its done post new code here.

Comment: @Julian, Not getting your Point.

Comment: @Dilip : Have you solved that display light black background when its going up/down issue?? If you have solved, then plz update your answer..

Comment: @MeetDoshi, Sorry not able to solve this issue, but i have overcome this issue by setting colour of app window to my app theme, so that way its less noticeable.

Comment: As I have a monochromatic background, I got rid of the light black background with a little (dirty) for loop. Here you go in your origin VC:
`for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
       view.backgroundColor = someColor
    }`

Answer (score 1):

For All Trying in Xamarin (C#) equivalent Code
From Answer by @hardik Thakkar above, Has the issue of Black backgound during animation, rest all good.

For POP

```
    CATransition transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
    transition.Duration = 0.4;
    transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionReveal;
    transition.Subtype = CAAnimation.TransitionFromTop;
    this.NavigationController.View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, nameof(CATransition));
```

For Push

```
    CATransition transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
    transition.Duration = 0.4;
    transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionReveal;
    transition.Subtype = CAAnimation.TransitionFromBottom;
    this.NavigationController.View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, nameof(CATransition));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing something like:

```
ViewController *myVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithFrame:OFF_SCREEN];
[navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:NO];
```

where OFF_SCREEN is some CGRect below the screen, like (0, 481, 320, 480). Then use an animation block to adjust the viewcontroller's view's frame.origin to be (0, 0). You would probably want to do the animate block in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

Comment: view controllers don't have an `initWithFrame:` initializer