# pushviewcontroller with zoom animation like ios photo app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I've two UIViewControllers. My first UIViewController shows various video thumbnails, photos and notes. And second controller is resposible for showing the selected video, photo or note in previous controller. I've also a UICollectionView in my first controller which lists everything just like Apple's Photo App in iOS.

I use "pushviewcontroller" to show my second view controller.

```
UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    FirstDetailViewController *fD=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstDetail"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: seconVCObj animated: YES];
```

But I want to open it with a zoom effect like ios photo app. When you touch a photo, app shows the photo like zooming.

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your desired effect as its providing multiple workable answers.

[Showing pushviewcontroller animation look like presentModalViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838219/showing-pushviewcontroller-animation-look-like-presentmodalviewcontroller)

[How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app)

one of the sample :

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo"context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: yourViewController animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```