# Animation properties of presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'm implementing a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` with a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to create a custom push animation. I want the push to look exactly like the slide up animation that `presentViewController` uses.

I'm currently using a duration of 0.4 seconds and `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` and it looks pretty darn close to the standard `presentViewController` animation but I don't want to just trust my eye.

Does anyone know what the animation properties are for `presentViewController` so that I can make sure I'm mimicking them exactly?

There are reasons why I'm doing a custom push animation instead of just using a modal view controller. Don't want that to distract from the question I've proposed.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code

```
UIViewController *yourViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

[UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: yourViewController animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I used animation duration 0.75 to look like modally view presentation.
check this [original thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838219/showing-pushviewcontroller-animation-look-like-presentmodalviewcontroller)