# How to present a View Controller without hiding the tabBar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, object

I have a UITabBarController with five view controllers in it. In one view controller, a button can be pressed to present a new ViewController, but the tabbar is covered. How can I present the controller and keep the tabbar visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you present something, it will cover entire screen.

The controller from where you want to present a new controller, make it as navigation controller rather keeping it as simple controller.

So, you can push the new controller on it rather than you present.

Comment: then i can't use the modalTransitionStyle to have an animation on the transition.T.T

Comment: could someone helps me?

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838219/showing-pushviewcontroller-animation-look-like-presentmodalviewcontroller to provide transition style while pushing view controller.

Comment: I am having a navigation controller but still the view didnt occupy the space for tabBar

Answer (score -1):

```
[<presentingViewControllerInstance> setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
```

Use currentContext as presentation style for the presenting view controller before presenting. No need to create a navigation controller and push.