# presentViewController:animated:completion display issues in new ios 5.1 UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5.1

I've ran into some problems using `UISplitViewController` with `presentViewController:animated:completion`.

To break the problem down into its simplest form, I've created a simple project with the master/detail template. In the project I've added a `+` button in the navigation bar of the master view. The plus button creates a navigation controller with a simple blank view. This navigation controller is then presented using `presentViewController:animated:completion`. However, the presented view only displays in the master view and when you dismiss it, the master view takes up the whole screen. I can't seem to understand what is going on. Anyone else encountered this problem? Here's the code.

```
- (void)showViewController:(id)sender
{
LMTestViewController *masterView = [[LMTestViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:masterView animated:YES completion:nil];
[masterView release];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A master/detail is a navigationControler both in the detail view and the masterView Controllers. You really can't put a NavigationController in another NavigationController. The View Hierarchy can get confused. Try presenting it Modally if you want a different navigationController.

Answer (score 6):

To present modally, use the window's root view controller.  Using anything else will cause things to become confused in the split view, especially when rotating, etc.

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:masterView
                                                  animated:YES
                                                completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the new view then ends up in the "detail" view only.

Comment: Any updates on this issue?  I'm presenting in the same way, and then resizing the view into a container UIView...it resizes correctly then eventually crashes after reloading the detailView